# Measuring the distance between NumPy matrixes

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy

This takes two sets of five random points stored as a NumPy matrix, and then calculates the NumPy matrix between a point of the first set and a point of the second set. While the code works, I feel it's inelegant, as if I was writing in PHP or some other language. How can the function `CalculateMatrixDistances` be improved?

```
import random
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import spatial

P=5
V=5

def CalculateMatrixDistances(MatRows,MatColums):
    numberRows=MatRows.shape[0]
    numberColumns=MatColums.shape[0]
    MatrixDistances=np.matrix( [0 for c in range(numberColumns)] )
    for r in range(numberRows):
        d=[scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean (MatRows[r],MatColums[c]) for c in range(numberColumns)]
        MatrixDistances = np.vstack([MatrixDistances, d])
    MatrixDistances=np.delete(MatrixDistances, (0), axis=0)
    return MatrixDistances

PositionP=np.random.rand(P,2)
PositionV=np.random.rand(V,2)

MatrixDistancesVP=CalculateMatrixDistances(PositionV,PositionP)

print PositionP
print PositionV
print MatrixDistancesVP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is already implemented as
[`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).
I'm going to assume that it's more optimised too.)

- Why initialise `MatrixDistances` to zero if you're only going to
  delete the first column regardless?  A matrix can also have zero for
  any dimension.

Some more general observations:

- As always, take a look at
  [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python
  conventions, in particular naming of functions and variables, but also
  missing whitespace.
- The imports could be more consistent; the `import spatial` isn't being
  used.
- A zero matrix should probably be allocated with `numpy.matlib.zeros`
  since it's shorter.
- In Python 2 use `xrange` if you don't need the full list; also use the
  function form of `print` for compatibility with Python 3 (it's also
  more consistent to use it this way).
- The repeated `vstack` may not be the most efficient option, but you
  should consult a profiler for that.

When keeping the naming it should still rather look like this maybe.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib
import scipy
import scipy.spatial

P, V = 5, 5

def CalculateMatrixDistances(MatRows, MatColums):
    numberRows = MatRows.shape[0]
    numberColumns = MatColums.shape[0]
    MatrixDistances = np.matlib.zeros((0, 5))
    for r in xrange(numberRows):
        d = [scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(MatRows[r], MatColums[c]) for c in xrange(numberColumns)]
        MatrixDistances = np.vstack([MatrixDistances, d])
    return MatrixDistances

PositionP = np.random.rand(P, 2)
PositionV = np.random.rand(V, 2)

MatrixDistancesVP = CalculateMatrixDistances(PositionV, PositionP)

print(PositionP)
print(PositionV)
print(MatrixDistancesVP)
print(scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(PositionV, PositionP))
```